# List not appearing properly in IE7/8. Images, border-radius, etc

Tags: html, css, list, sass, css-position

First off, the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/MhFk4/2/

In IE9 everything is working fine, but IE8 & below I'm running into issues.. on the development site, only one of the buttons shows up in IE8 at all (yet on the fiddle it shows up, but the border-radius isn't working properly?.)

Here's the actual development site to see what IE8 does there: http://tinyurl.com/bxy449e

```
.view-home-cta-view {
ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 40px 0 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 380px;

    li {
        float:left;
        margin: 0 25px 0 0;
        position:relative;

        .views-field-field-cta-image {
            border: 10px solid #fff;
            @include border-radius(150px);
            width:270px;
            box-shadow:0 0 25px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);

            -moz-background-clip: padding; 
            -webkit-background-clip: padding-box; 
            background-clip: padding-box;

            img {
                max-width:100%;
                height: auto;
                @include border-radius(140px);
            }
        }
        .views-field-field-regular-link {
            font-family: $o;
            font-size:22px;
            width:100%;
            position:absolute;
            bottom:14px; // 60px up from bottom
            left: 0;
            z-index: 3000;
            a {
                color:#fff;
                text-decoration: none;
                background: $green;
                display:block;
                text-align:center;
                line-height:22px;
                padding: 13px 0 15px;
                @include border-radius(5px);
                box-shadow:0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
                @include transition(0.5s);
                &:hover {
                    background: lighten($green,5%);
                }
            }
        }
        .views-field-field-attachment-link {
            font-family: $o;
            font-size:16px;
            width:100%;
            position:absolute;
            bottom:-20px;
            left:0;
            a {
                color:#fff;
                text-decoration: none;
                background: $brown;
                display:block;
                text-align:center;
                @include border-radius(0 0 5px 5px);
                margin: 0 20px;
                padding: 8px 0 10px;
                line-height:16px;
                box-shadow:0 0 7px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
                @include transition(0.5s);
                &:hover {
                    background: lighten($brown,5%);
                }
            }
        }

        &.views-row-last {
            margin-right: 0;
        }
    }
}}
```

All the SCSS code is in the JSfiddle (with mixins and variables for color). If anyone could shine some light on this I'd appreciate it, thanks!

Comment: Could be problems with your current html doc-type.  try rebuilding your HTML layout on a proper HTML5 doc-type instead of whatever you are using at the given moment. Then see if your images disappear when you render in IE8 mode.

Comment: I have voted to close this question because it's too localized, and unlikely to help any future visitors.  You should pare down your example so that it contains just enough code to demonstrate the problem, without anything extra. Doing this can be a lot of work, but it's a critical part of the process of troubleshooting your problem.

Comment: @blachawk the doctype didn't seem to change anything unfortunately, but thanks for the suggestion! I've noticed that the problem involves z-indexing, I've managed to make the second link appear by giving it a z-index underneath the first one. However, adding a z-index for the image area's div didn't do anything so I'm still rather confused about the whole thing.

Comment: Actually managed to resolve it with more `z-index` fiddling. Applying a `z-index` to each container div inside of the `li` and then an extra `z-index` on the `li` itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here revolved around `z-index`, I managed to solve it by applying a `z-index` to each container div inside of the `li` element and also add an extra `z-index` on the `li` itself.